# How to open file using vscode tasks in remote vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-tasks

I'd like to be able to use the [new vscode tasks feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to open a file in remote vscode. This is useful because I have a bunch of symlinked log files in tmp that I would like to open, and I don't want to type their whole name every time. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
    {
        "label": "$(play) open log file",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "code /tmp/logfile.INFO",
        "group": "build",
    },
```

If I run the same command in the normal vscode terminal, it opens the file correctly. If I run it in the task, the environment doesn't have vscode's bin in the path. If I change code in the task to use the direct path of the remove vscode, it then complains saying "Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal."

I'm unclear if this fails because it is remote vscode or if it fails because it's not possible to open code in a task. Either way it'd be nice to do so :)